# JQuery Autocomplete textbox asp.net Limit result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am working on an autocomplete function for a text box and need too fetch  ten results at one time and with an option which say get more hyperlink. Currently it fetches all the results.

My code so far is attached below. can you please provide guidance?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#<%=txtEmployeeName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $("#loading").show();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "AccountDisclosureSearch.aspx/SearchEmpByText",
                        data: "{ 'empName':'" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split(";")[0],
                                    val: item.split(";")[1]
                                //    name: item.split("|")[0]
                                }
                            }))
                            $("#loading").hide();
                        },

                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                            $("#loading").hide();
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {

                 //   $("#<%=hempid.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
                    storeEmployee(i.item.label, 0, i.item.val);

                },

                 open: function(){
                $('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '220px');
                },
                minLength: 3

            });
        });
```

Comment: In your backend query you can set limit like LIMIT 0,10

Comment: @stackoverflkowfan Do you have access to the AccountDisclosureSearch.aspx probably yes, you can add an extra item in the JSON response so automatically the required element would be added..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `maxResults` or `maxShowItems` like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#<%=txtEmployeeName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
             maxResults:10,
             or
             maxShowItems:10,
             or 
             maxHeight: 150,
             source: function (request, response) {
             //whatever you have
             }
            });
});
```

For more information check [Here](https://github.com/anseki/jquery-ui-autocomplete-scroll)

Comment: Thanks Lalit but I also need a hypoerlink at the bottom to show the remaining or next 10 ...am struggling with that

Comment: is that necessary for you to use hyperlink?otherwise you could use `maxHeight` with scrollbar

Comment: I can try the maxheight however the hyperlink is the orig requirement :)

Comment: This is the remember to accept the answer by click the tick mark which you forgot. @stackoverflkowfan